# Why are two capacitors used in capacitive wireless power transfer instead of one?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, telecommunications

I am an engineering student.  I am studying wireless power transfer (WPT) theory.

I understand that from a theoretical point of view it is possible to do capacitive wireless power transfer using a single capacitor, so one plate is used as a transmitter and the other one as a receiver.

In some scientific papers I've seen circuits having two capacitors placed in parallel, so we have two transmitting plates and two receiving plates.

Why this choice? In order to support a larger amount of power?

I've attached an image as example, where P1 and P3 are the transmit side and P2 and P4 are the receive side.

The human skin tissue is the dielectric of these capacitors.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your image presents powering some implanted device and not measuring something which happens under the skin nor sending commands to implanted devices? Maybe you should reveal more details of what's going on.

Comment: Is the second capacitor the signal return path?